# How to find polynomial in Q[x] with specified non-rational root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, radicals, nested-radicals

I found the following exercise in a textbook:

> **Exercise 11.2.**  Find a polynomial with rational coefficients that has $$\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}}}$$ as a root.
>
> (Source: *Integers, Polynomials, and Rings*, by Ronald Irving, p. 178.)

(In what follows, I'll use $A$ to refer to the real number mentioned in the exercise.)

I don't see how one can use any of the material preceding this exercise to solve this problem.  Is there a simple algorithm I'm missing?

FWIW, according to *Mathematica*, the *minimal* polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ (rather than $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) for $A$ is $$f(x) = 205891132094649 x^{30}\\
-2058911320946490 x^{29}\\
+3774670755068565 x^{28}\\
+26689591197454500 x^{27}\\
+103288717934148915 x^{26}\\
+120743710577284158 x^{25}\\
+979596962250571665 x^{24}\\
+25113634383890520 x^{23}\\
+5534307029830645755 x^{22}\\
+2990868225888744630 x^{21}\\
+21801155360211123894 x^{20}\\
+17387732153625824880 x^{19}\\
+64771042155589328805 x^{18}\\
+57930026664623685390 x^{17}\\
+151839596608592644350 x^{16}\\
+130602662006312722752 x^{15}\\
+287146843258295642445 x^{14}\\
+205985143814386139730 x^{13}\\
+438236071775524498185 x^{12}\\
+219265354586979477900 x^{11}\\
+528283318408667131986 x^{10}\\
+131814318593663712900 x^9\\
+480947808117639761190 x^8\\
+1840154837168719440 x^7\\
+305643459116482257195 x^6\\
+76077403177127438538 x^5\\
+115600935241965908070 x^4\\
+59228312720004507600 x^3\\
+14798700839480423580 x^2\\
+16440663358610960040 x\\
+3233167181917838873$$

It's hard for me to imagine that the textbook's author intended students to compute a solution like that by hand.  Is there a (not necessarily minimal) polynomial $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, with $g(A) = 0$, that is easier to compute than $f(x)$ above?

Comment: It looks correct, as far as I can see because of the radicals, that the minimal polynomial's degree is $\;30\;$ , so if there's some "simplification" it is going to be minimal: the polynomial is going to be monstruous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x &=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}}} \\
\displaystyle x - \frac13 &=& \displaystyle -\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}}} \\
\displaystyle \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 &=& \displaystyle 2 + \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}} \\
\displaystyle \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 - 2 &=& \displaystyle \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}} \\
\displaystyle \left( \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 - 2 \right)^5 &=& \displaystyle 1-\sqrt[3]{7} \\
\displaystyle \left( \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 - 2 \right)^5 - 1 &=& \displaystyle -\sqrt[3]{7} \\
\displaystyle \left( \left( \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 - 2 \right)^5 - 1 \right)^3 &=& \displaystyle -7 \\
\displaystyle \left( \left( \left( x - \frac13 \right)^2 - 2 \right)^5 - 1 \right)^3 + 7 &=& 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Wow, so simple.  I don't know what I was thinking.  I'm embarrassed.

Comment: Nice work !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$x=\frac{1}{3}-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[5]{1-\sqrt[3]{7}}}$$
Thus, $$\left(\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2-2\right)^5-1\right)^3+7=0.$$

Comment: Both answers are the same,  yet the fact remains: it is an ugly monster of polynomial...

Comment: @DonAntonio Only if you fall for the trap and expand it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed so...